# Taxonomy GetAllTerms on level 2

Tags: taxonomy

We have a termset with parent term name "State" and with child term "City".
I want to show all child terms "City" in a dropdownlist.
Who can I retrive only child terms from this termset?

Answer (score 1):

you need to first finding the termset "State".

for ex:   TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(SPContext.Current.Site);
          // Get a reference to the store
          TermStore store = session.TermStores[_tTaxonomyField.SspId];

```
      TermSet _termSet = store.GetTermSet(_tTaxonomyField.TermSetId);

       foreach (Term termSet in _termSet.Terms)
        {
             // all child term found here
        }
```

hope this help.